# Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration:java:null'

Tags: java, mule, drools

I'm getting the below `ClassNotFoundException` error while executing drools in my code. The above error is not seen in versions Anypoint Studio 7.0.0.Final to 7.22.0.Final. It only occurs in version 7.23.0.Final and 7.24.0.Final

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>${drools.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
    <version>${drools.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
    <version>${drools.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
    <version>${drools.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Error Message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration:java:null'
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.addDialect(KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:394)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.buildDialectConfigurationMap(KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:380)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.init(KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:235)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.init(KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:187)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.<init>(KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:155)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.getBuilderConfiguration(AbstractKieProject.java:302)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.createKnowledgeBuilder(AbstractKieProject.java:288)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieProject.java:213)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieModule.java:201)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.createKieBase(AbstractKieModule.java:215)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.createKieBase(KieContainerImpl.java:406)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.getKieBase(KieContainerImpl.java:374)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.getKieBaseFromKieSessionModel(KieContainerImpl.java:575)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:551)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:521)
    at com.drools.example.RulesEngine.executeJobRules(RulesEngine.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mule.extensions.java.internal.JavaModuleUtils.invokeMethod(JavaModuleUtils.java:56)
    at org.mule.extensions.java.internal.operation.JavaInvokeOperations.invokeStatic(JavaInvokeOperations.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.ReflectiveMethodComponentExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ReflectiveMethodComponentExecutor.java:80)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:227)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:849)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:813)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.ReflectiveMethodComponentExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodComponentExecutor.java:79)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ReflectiveMethodOperationExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodOperationExecutor.java:64)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.InterceptableOperationExecutorWrapper.execute(InterceptableOperationExecutorWrapper.java:60)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.lambda$null$3(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:142)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:227)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:849)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:813)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.lambda$executeWithInterceptors$9(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:142)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:1765)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:33)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3006)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:385)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$1.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:260)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$1.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:253)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$1.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:260)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$1.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:253)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:113)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$1.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:260)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$1.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:253)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$1.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:260)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$1.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:253)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:113)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$1.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:260)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$1.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:253)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:213)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmit(FluxFlatMap.java:497)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:935)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:89)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryWhen.java:134)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onNext(FluxSubscribeOn.java:151)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.runAsync(FluxPublishOn.java:389)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(FluxPublishOn.java:473)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:111)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration
    at org.drools.core.common.ProjectClassLoader.tryDefineType(ProjectClassLoader.java:197)
    at org.drools.core.common.ProjectClassLoader.loadType(ProjectClassLoader.java:187)
    at org.drools.core.common.ProjectClassLoader.loadClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:154)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.addDialect(KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:388)
    ... 97 more
```

Comment: You have any rule configuration ? The dialect is not set & is null.

Comment: @Kris I have a rule configuration in my .drl file and it has `dialect "mvel"`. Is this okay or should I configure something else to get rid of this error?

Comment: Is it the same Mule Runtime version for each run in Studio? How are you calling drools from the mule app? Also add the versions of Mule modules/connectors.

Comment: @aled I tried in Mule version (4.1.4 - 4.2.1) and Anypoint studio version (7.3.4) but the above scenario works fine in mule 3 (with drools 7.23.0.Final & 7.24.0.Final)

Answer (score 0):

Mule 4 is not compatible with Mule 3 in that regard. Mule 4 deprecated support for Drools: 
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/migration-connectors

You can use Drools directly in your Java code, however it would probably make more sense to create a custom module -think of your own Drools connector- with Mule SDK to reuse it more easily in your application ls.

Comment: I'm using custom code to run drools in mule 4 similar to this article [link](https://dzone.com/articles/drools-with-mule-4)

Answer (score 0):

I have just been through this process of getting Drools to run inside a Mule 4 application, and also came across this issue. The problem is that Mule doesn't allow classes to load classes from other dependencies via reflection, unless you explicitly allow using sharedLibraries in the mule-maven-plugin. This is what mine looks like, and it works using Drools 7.27.0.Final

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>mule-application</classifier>
        <sharedLibraries>
            <sharedLibrary>
                <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
                <artifactId>drools-workbench-models-guided-dtable</artifactId>
            </sharedLibrary>
            <sharedLibrary>
                <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
                <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            </sharedLibrary>
            <sharedLibrary>
                <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
                <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            </sharedLibrary>
            <sharedLibrary>
                <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            </sharedLibrary>
            <sharedLibrary>
                <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
            </sharedLibrary>
            <sharedLibrary>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
                <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            </sharedLibrary>
        </sharedLibraries>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I also had to add an explicit dependency on org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj, which is used by Drools.
Some of those libraries may not be required, I just copied all of my Drools dependencies in there